# jquery multiselect after change removing selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

have big problem.
have jquery multiselect plugin [from here](https://github.com/michael/multiselect)

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'my url',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'data': data1, 'data2': 'data2'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.length >= 1){
                $('#selector').find('option').remove();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if ($("#selector option[value='" + value.email + "']").length == 0){
                        $("#selector").append('<option value="'+ value.email +'" data-id="'+value.id+'" data-name="' + value.name + '" data-surname="' + value.surname + '">'+ value.name + ' ' + value.surname + ' ' + ' (' + value.email + ') sent (' + value.sent + ')' +'</option>').multiselect("destroy").multiselect( { sortable : false }  );
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#selector').find('option').remove();
                $('#selector').append('').multiselect("destroy").multiselect( { sortable : false }  );
            }      
        }
    });
```

and after change (call this function, whitch selecting cantacts from other list) my selected values disapears

Comment: Does your `data` contain any items?

Comment: Is data1 an object? Where is it declared? data2 is a string. data: {'data': data1, 'data2': 'data2'},

Comment: Are you using the older, unsupported version of Multiselect (your link) or version 2.0?

Comment: try call 'destroy' method of multiselect before the .each loop. and call multiselect again after .each loop.

Comment: yes..
i made screen shot maybe for clearer understanding.. [here it is](http://i.imgur.com/IOBj9cE.png)

and when i change on group, my available section is good, but my selected section becomes empty.. 
i need to be able to choose contacts from several groups, not from one.

and @Callebe sad, but didn't worked

Comment: and if someone have other like that plugin, which i could use, i would like to know it too :)